# How select2 works with appended rows in a table dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I am appending rows for each rows contains employee and package dropdown, employee dropdown for single select and package dropdown for multiselect but whenever i append new row previous all rows loose its select2 functionality. Im using metronic theme build in select2.Here are the codes. Thank you for the help.

```
  <table id="employeeTable" class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Employee</th>
             <th>Selected Packages</th>
             <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SelectedEmployeeIds.Count; i++)
         {
             <tr id="row-@i">
                 <td>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label asp-for="SelectedEmployeeIds[i]">Employee:</label>
                         <select asp-for="SelectedEmployeeIds[i]" data-control="select2" data-placeholder="Select employee" data-dropdown-css-class="w-250px" asp-items="Model.Employees" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-hidden="true" required>
                             <option></option>
                         </select>
                         <span asp-validation-for="SelectedEmployeeIds[i]" class="text-danger"></span>
                     </div>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label asp-for="SelectedPackageIds[i]">Selected Packages:</label>
                         <select asp-for="SelectedPackageIds[i]" 
                         data-control="select2"
                         data-dropdown-css-class="w-250px" 
                         data-placeholder="Select packages"
                         data-allow-clear="true" multiple="multiple" 
                         asp-items="Model.Packages" class="form-select form-select-sm customClass" required></select>
                         <option></option>
                         <span asp-validation-for="SelectedPackageIds[i]" class="text-danger"></span>
                     </div>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <div>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mb-2" onclick="addEmployeeRow(this)">Add</button><br>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="removeEmployeeRow(this)">Remove</button>
                     </div>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         }

     </tbody>
 </table>
```

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function addEmployeeRow(button) {
            var newRow = $(button).closest('tr').clone();
            newRow.find('select').val(null); // Clear selected values
            newRow.find('.text-danger').text('');
           
            var newIndex = $('#employeeTable tbody tr').length;
            newRow.attr('id', 'row-' + newIndex);
           
       // Update the name attributes for the new row
            newRow.find('select').each(function () {
                var oldName = $(this).attr('name');
                var newName = oldName.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '[' + newIndex + ']');
                $(this).attr('name', newName);
                // Destroy previous Select2 instance, if any
                if ($(this).hasClass('select2-hidden-accessible')) {
                    $(this).next('.select2-container').remove();
                }
                // Initialize Select2 for the new select elements
                $(this).select2({
                });
            });
            $('#employeeTable tbody').append(newRow);
        }
        function removeEmployeeRow(button) {
            $(button).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Can you try initialising `select2` on the new row, *after* it's been appended to the DOM?

Comment: yes, I initialize 

  // Initialize Select2 for the new select elements
                $(this).select2({
                });

Comment: No, that's *before* you add them to the DOM `$('#employeeTable tbody').append(newRow);` - try moving the `.select2({})` line to *after* the `.append(newRow)` line (will need some additional changes, not just move the line)

Comment: this way it still not worked

Comment: ok, worth a try

Comment: i dont know why previous rows select2 functionality lose everytime when new row is appended only current row have select2 functionality but it also lose when I add another row.